# pool.connect not responding after sometime postgres nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg

I am pooling postgres every 10 seconds for fetching data from a table but after sometime, it doesnot connect.

scheduler is node-cron:

```
cron.schedule('*/10 * * * * *', () =>{
    sync.doSync();
},{scheduled: true})
```

my doSync function:

```
function doSync(){
   console.log("presync")

    db.pool.connect(async(err, connection) => {
        console.log("connected")
        if(err){
            console.log("error:",err)
        }

        const stored = parseInt(await getStored("mystorage.txt"));
        const fetched = parseInt(await fetchLatest(connection));

                const query = getQuery(fetched)
                try {
                    const cursor = await connection.query(new Cursor(query));
                    await processResult(cursor,fetched);
                    connection.release();
                } catch (err) {
                    setTimeout(doSync, 10000)
                }
        }
    })
}
```

in db.js

```
module.exports.pool = new Pool(config.postgres)
```

It works for 30 second, i get "presync" and
"connected" for 3 times from console.log and after that only "presync".
?How do i solve this issue? I need to query from database constantly and i am also confused if i should release the connection early as i did? I am new to backend and trying to understand the proper way of doing things. Can someone help?

Comment: My guess is, your query is failing and the catch {} does not release the connection. It is much better to move the `connection.release()` to a finally {} block - this way, the connection will get released even in presence of errors. Also, your retry-only error handling could use some logging (at least a console.error) to aid in debugging.

Comment: the query takes around 3s to return the results using the index scan. i moved connection.release to the catch block though. i do have the err.message but didnot show in the code here.